# Key error while using django crispy forms for login

Tags: python, django, django-crispy-forms, django-1.7

I was trying to create a login form in django using crispy forms. During login authentication I have two fields: **email_id** and **password**. but in browser it only showing password field, and have following error:

Django version is 1.7

```
WARNING:root:Could not resolve form field 'email_id'.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/crispy_forms/utils.py", line 74, in render_field
    field_instance = form.fields[field]
KeyError: u'email_id'
```

The snapshot of the webpage being rendered is :

[image: Snapshot of page being rendered]

The model of the User for which I am trying to login is : **model.py**

```
class User(models.Model):
    user_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title_id = models.ForeignKey('Title')
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    middle_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True, default='')
    password = models.CharField(max_length=100)  # will be changed according to hash used
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    alternate_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email_id = models.EmailField()
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    profession_id = models.ForeignKey('Profession')
    house_no = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    city_id = models.ForeignKey('City')
    country_id = models.ForeignKey('Country')
    state_id = models.ForeignKey('State')
    locality_id = models.ForeignKey('Locality')
```

The class for login in the file **view.py** is:

```
class LoginView(generic.FormView):
    form_class = LoginForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('profile')
    template_name = 'login.html'
    #model = User

    def form_valid(self, form):
        email_id = form.cleaned_data['email_id']
        password = form.cleaned_data['password']
        user = authenticate(email_id=email_id, password=password)
        if user is not None and user.is_active:
            login(self.request, user)
            return super(LoginView, self).form_valid(form)
        else:
            return self.form_invalid(form)
```

The class for login form in **forms.py** is:

```
class LoginForm(AuthenticationForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(LoginForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()
        self.helper.layout = Layout(
            'email_id',
            'password',
            ButtonHolder(
                Submit('login', 'Login', css_class= 'btn-primary')
            )
        )
```

Comment: You're not by any chance importing the built-in `django.contrib.auth.models.User` model, are you?

Comment: @trpt4him No i am not using built-in User model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can see (I am taking an educated guess, as you have not included your imports anywhere), you're using `django.contrib.auth.forms.AuthenticationForm` as the parent class for your `LoginForm` class, which is being used in `LoginView`.

The only two fields on the `AuthenticationForm` class are `username` and `password`, but you are trying to access an `email_id` field in your `Layout` object in `LoginForm.__init__`. This will not work, because there is no field named `email_id` to access.

The `password` field happens to show up on your page because there is a `password` field on `AuthenticationForm`, but if you're wanting to add `email_id` then you will need to either:

- add `email_id` as a form Field on your `LoginForm` class, or
- create a `ModelForm` using your `User` model, or
- read [this guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-a-custom-user-model) on how to specify a custom user model, and the steps necessary to integrate with django's auth app (I think this is what you want)

I am not sure whether you are trying to create a custom user model or not, but since you seem to be using the `django.contrib.auth.authenticate` function in your view (again, an educated guess, as there are no imports) then it seems that you're not following the correct pattern.